# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API interfaces must not extend other interfaces Retrofit 2

Tags: android, inheritance, retrofit

I am having the next problem using Retrofit 2 beta 2:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API interfaces must not extend other interfaces.
```

This is because I have one interface for the API of Retrofit like this:

```
public interface RetrofitBaseAPI {

    @POST
    Call<LoginResp> login(@Url String url, @Body LoginReq loginReq);

    @POST
    Call<String> logout(@Url String url, @Header("Cookie") String sid);
}
```

For example, one of them is this one:

```
public interface RetrofitWiserLinkAPI extends RetrofitBaseAPI {

    @GET("/rs/DeviceIdentification")
    Call<DeviceId> getDeviceIdentification(@Header("Cookie") String sid);
}
```

And then, I have three other interfaces, the three of them extends from this RetrofitBaseAPI interface.

When I try to call the retrofit.create(Class class) with the given interface, I always receive this error.

As far as I was reading, the only solution is to create three independents interfaces. Is it true? Anybody knows another solution?

I find a little bit weird that we need to duplicate code, but well, maybe there is a reason I don't understand.....

Thanks in advance!

Thanks,

EDIT: Same problem using the final Retrofit 2 release version. I guess it is a limitation from Retrofit....

Comment: no it is not possible. You can read more [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/676)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! And the restriction is for any particular reason of performance, desing, etc??? Or is it only to reduce the possible use cases?

Comment: @zapotec  "Retrofit favors composition. This PR adds inheritance." said someone...

Comment: I got the same problem. have you figured it out without creating three independents interfaces?

Comment: No, sorry but the only way is by creating completely different interfaces (which means in some point, to copy/paste some code for the repeated methods)

Comment: When you receive a solution you simply need to mark an answer as accepted, you don't have to change a question title. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not possible to have a base Retrofit interface.

[JakeWharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) - the author of Retrofit:

> Retrofit favors composition over inheritance. One interface per service.

So as you already found out, the only solution is to create three independents interfaces.

Comment: What a pitty :-/